# Not receiving anything in Mail.app inbox

Tags: mail.app, email, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro, and I use Mail.app. Everything used to work fine with my POP account.

However, last week my incoming mail showed that it was being downloaded to my inbox, but it never showed up. I have rebuilt my inbox, and also re-initiated, and configured my POP account, but the same problem remains.

I have also an IMAP account, which worked fine before and since this occurrence.

Any clue or hints on what is going on?

Comment: Do you have any Rules set for dealing with your mail?

Are there ANY other folders in your Mail set that could be holding your incoming mail?

Comment: To be clear:  you are accessing the same mailbox via two different protocols, POP and IMAP, correct?  May I ask why you wouldn't just use IMAP?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your mailbox quota may have been exceeded, thus making it so you don't receive any new messages. If that's not the case, then I would completely remove the account from Mail or explore around `~/Library/Mail` and edit/remove some files if necessary.